# Cython parallelism and stencils

Tags: python, cython

After an intensive use of numba, I am coming back to cython to parallelize some time consuming functions. Hereafter, a base example :

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

from cython import boundscheck, wraparound
from cython.parallel import parallel, prange

@boundscheck(False)
@wraparound(False)
def cytest1(double[:,::1] a, double[:,::1] b, int ix1, int ix2, int iz1, int iz2):

    cdef int ix
    cdef int iz

    for ix in range(ix1, ix2):
        for iz in range(iz1, iz2):
            b[ix, iz] = 0.5*(a[ix+1, iz] - a[ix-1, iz])
    return b


@boundscheck(False)
@wraparound(False)
def cytest2(double[:,::1] a, double[:,::1] b, int ix1, int ix2, int iz1, int iz2):

    cdef int ix
    cdef int iz

    with nogil, parallel():
        for ix in prange(ix1, ix2):
            for iz in range(iz1, iz2):
                b[ix, iz] = 0.5*(a[ix+1, iz] - a[ix-1, iz])

    return b
```

When compiling these two functions (with openmp flag), and calling them as follows :

```
nx, nz = 1024, 1024

a = np.random.rand(nx, nz)
b = np.zeros_like(a)

Nit = 1000
ti = time.time()
for i in range(Nit):
    cytest1(a, b, 5, nx-5, 0, nz)
print('cytest1 : {:.3f} s.'.format(time.time() - ti))

ti = time.time()
for i in range(Nit):
    cytest2(a, b, 5, nx-5, 0, nz)
print('cytest2 : {:.3f} s.'.format(time.time() - ti))
```

I obtain these execution times :

```
cytest1 : 1.757 s.
cytest2 : 1.861 s.
```

When the parallel function is executed, I can see my 4 cpu-s in action, but the execution time is nearly the same that the one obtained with the serial function. I tried to move `prange` to the inner loop, but for worst results. I also tried some different `schedule` options but without success.

I am clearly missing something, but what ? Is `prange` unable to chunk the loop with a code trying to access n+X/n-X elements ?

**EDIT :**

My setup :

```
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
MemTotal        : 8052556 kB
Python          : 3.5.2
cython          : 0.28.2
Numpy           : 1.14.2 
Numba           : 0.37.0
```

The setup.py :

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext


ext_modules = [
    Extension("stencil",
              ["stencil.pyx"],
              libraries=["m"],
              extra_compile_args=["-O3", "-ffast-math", "-march=native", "-fopenmp"],
              extra_link_args=['-fopenmp'],
              )
]

setup(
  name="stencil",
  cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
  ext_modules=ext_modules
)
```

Comment: This is a memory bound task, thus the parallelization doesn’t help as it does not increase the memory bandwidth. Even worse: it has some overhead which makes it slower or may lead to more cache misses. So far my theory.. you could test it by using something cpu-heavy like sin or cos  in your formula and see if there is some gain from parallelization in this case.

Comment: actually, on my machine I have 2.9ms vs. 0.27ms per call for your code. So there is a speed-up.

Comment: On a Core i7-4771 I get 1.6s for the single threaded and 1.0s for an multithreaded approach. (Numba 0.38RC1). So if you have not the worst processor or Ram there should be optimization potential.

Comment: @ead On which machine are you? (working system/processor/compiler,..) I get quite the same results with Numba and Cython (1.4-1.6 ms/1 ms). I am on Windows,Python 3.6,MSVCv.1900.

Comment: @max9111 I have windows, Intel Xeon E5-2620 @ 2.1 Ghz, Python 3.6, Cython 0.27

Comment: @max9111 can you see speed you calculates `  sin(0.5*(a[ix+1, iz] - a[ix-1, iz]))` ?

Comment: @ead Tested it with on Linux (gcc 5.4,Python 3.6, Cython 0.27) This gave negative speedup with parfor (1.36/1.46)

Comment: @ead got really weird timing when using ` sin(0.5*(a[ix+1, iz] - a[ix-1, iz]))`  Windows,MSVC19(3.81/1.55) Linux,gcc 5.4(14.25/11.26) Using defaults, but enabling OpenMP So I think the most important thing is to optimize the C-Compiler...

Comment: `sin(0.5*(a[ix+1, iz] - a[ix-1, iz]))` gives me **14.20/7.04** [linux, gcc 5.4], but the code described in my post still gives me **1.77/1.89** !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer will be a lot of guesswork, but as we will see: a lot depends on the hardware, so it is not easy to explain without having the same hardware at hand.

The first question is: What is the bottle-neck? By looking at the code I would assume, that this is a memory-bound task.

To make it more clear-cut, let's do only the following operation in the loop:

```
 b[ix, iz] = (a[ix+1, iz])
```

So there is no calculation, only memory accesses.

I use Intel Xeon E5-2620 @ 2.1 Ghz with 2 processors and `%timeit`-magic reports:

```
>>> %timeit cytest1(a,b,5, nx-5, 0, nz)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.99 ms per loop

>>> %timeit cytest2(a,b,5, nx-5, 0, nz)
The slowest run took 234.48 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 324 µs per loop
```

As we can see, some caching is going on. We have 2 arrays, each 8Mb - that means 16Mb of data which has to be "touched". Every processor on my machine has 15Mb cache - so for a single thread the data is evicted from cache before it can be reused,but if both processors are used there are 20Mb of fast cache - and thus big enough to keep all of the data.

That means the speed-up we see is due to larger amount of fast-memory (cache) which can be utilized by the parallelized version.

Let's increase the size of the arrays, so the cache isn't big enough even for the paralleliized version:

```
....
>>> nx, nz = 10240, 10240 #100 times bigger
....

>>> %timeit cytest1(a,b,5, nx-5, 0, nz)
1 loop, best of 3: 238 ms per loop

>>> %timeit cytest2(a,b,5, nx-5, 0, nz)
10 loops, best of 3: 99.3 ms per loop
```

Now it is about 2 times faster, which is easy to explain: two processors have twice the memory-bandwidth compared to one processor and both are utilized by the parallel version.

We get very similar results for your formula

```
b[ix, iz] = 0.5*(a[ix+1, iz] - a[ix-1, iz])
```

which is not surprisingly - there are not enough calculations to make it CPU-bound.

`sin`  and `cos`  are pretty CPU-intensive operations, so using them will make the calculation CPU-bound (see appendix for the whole code):

```
...
b[ix, iz] = sin(a[ix+1, iz])
...
>>> %timeit cytest1(a,b,5, nx-5, 0, nz)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.6 s per loop

>>> %timeit cytest2(a,b,5, nx-5, 0, nz)
1 loop, best of 3: 217 ms per loop
```

This yields speed-up of 8, which is quite reasonable for my machine.

Obviously, for other machines/architectures different behaviors can be observed. But in a nutshell:

1. I would not expect much speed-up for your formula - the task is memory-bound, so the question is, whether you can achieve a higher bandwidth of memory-accesses or not.
2. For more CPU-intensive calculation you should be able to see at least some speed-up, which yet depends on your hardware.

---

Listing (on windows, use `-fopenmp` on linux):

```
%%cython --compile-args=/openmp --link-args=/openmp 
from cython.parallel import parallel, prange
from cython import boundscheck, wraparound
from libc.math cimport sin

@boundscheck(False)
@wraparound(False)
def cytest1(double[:,::1] a, double[:,::1] b, int ix1, int ix2, int iz1, int iz2):

    cdef int ix
    cdef int iz

    for ix in range(ix1, ix2):
        for iz in range(iz1, iz2):
            b[ix, iz] =sin(a[ix+1, iz])
    return b


@boundscheck(False)
@wraparound(False)
def cytest2(double[:,::1] a, double[:,::1] b, int ix1, int ix2, int iz1, int iz2):

    cdef int ix
    cdef int iz

    with nogil, parallel():
        for ix in prange(ix1, ix2):
            for iz in range(iz1, iz2):
                b[ix, iz] = sin(a[ix+1, iz])

    return b
```

Comment: Thanks for this analysis. Things are now clear to me !